# How to get number of documents returned in a cursor from a query in mongodb in C?

Tags: c, mongodb, libmongoc

I am looking for a good way to get the number of documents returned by a query to mongodb in C language.

I am looking for something what cursor.count() does in python. But cannot find anything that could help me when I have to do the same work in C language.